# Shifting in pixel after subsetting with gdalwarp

Tags: raster, clip, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, subset

I am trying to subset multiple image to **smaller Area of interest** 
I have tried with **gdal_translate** & **gdalwarp** in commandline but it **causes slight shift in pixel in the output raster** after cropping/sub-setting image into smaller place by using 1st command.

**my 1st command is**

```
gdal_translate -projwin 5.83 47.86 10.98 45.65 -of GTiff inputraster.tif outputraster.tif
```

I have also tried in qgis (which is basically same thing) by clip raster by extent which also causes shift in pixel from original.

**My 2nd command**

```
gdalwarp -tr 0.01 0.01 -te 5.83 47.86 10.98 45.65 -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -r near -tap -of GTiff input.tif output.tif outputraster.tif
```

which causes **changes in pixel value the highest raster value decreases** in 210 from 215 in original raster

Comment: Define "shift in pixel". Something must change in pixels if you change the pixel size.Try to clarify what is the desired result. You can solve the gdal_translate failure by reading the document https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html about -projwin.

Comment: I did not want to add the -tr 0.01 0.01 pixel resolution but then the output raster changes its resolution. is not possible to get the subset with gdalwarp?

Comment: I have solved it with gdal_translate :)

Comment: I would call the result from gdalwarp as subset even the resolution changes but I guess that you mean a result that has pixels locations matching with the original pixels. With gdalwarp you should get that result by using option `-tap`. Other option is to be very careful with `-projwin` and use values which fit exactly with the pixel borders. Instead of `-4.14722 31.18842 24.90383 70.48050` I would try with values `-4.15 31.19 24.90 70.48` to match with the resolution of -0.01. In your original request the size of the projwin was not a multiple of pixel size and thus GDAL adjusts the size.

Comment: I have carefully put all coordinates with gdal_translate still there is a shift in  subset raster from original raster. I have tried with gdalwarp with '-tap' although the pixel does not shift but the values of my classified raster is changed  now. Please suggest

Comment: Do you mean gdalwarp? I might be interested in having a look if you can provide source data and exact commands that you use.

Comment: command 1 which also causes slight shift in pixel position in the output raster---`gdal_translate -projwin 5.83 47.86 10.98 45.65 -of GTiff  inputraster.tif outputraster.tif`

Comment: command 2--for gdalwarp I used with your suggestion which does not shift the position of pixel in raster but changes the raster pixel value--------------`gdalwarp -tr 0.01 0.01 -te 5.83 47.86 10.98 45.65 -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -r near -tap -of GTiff input.tif output.tif`

Comment: Add lines "origin" and "pixel size" from gdalinfo. Edit your question instead of adding new info in comments. With what method did you check that the pixel value changed? Are you sure that it is not just how it shows on screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103657/discussion-between-tua-and-user30184).